# Why flutter take so much ram to build the grable build after second time I opened the project

Tags: flutter, gradlew

When I create the new file of the flutter project the first time it's run smoothly and no issues occur, when I start these projects again after some period of time, the Gradle build is stuck and so much ram usage by the OpenJDK binary platform. After some time pc crashed.

[Task manager screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cHh3.png)

Here is the flutter doctor's output

```
    [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.556], locale en-US)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
    ✗ cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✗] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    ✗ Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2021.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.66.2)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

So please tell me how do I fix it?

Comment: Do you have an internet connection? Maybe the project is downloading some resources that's why it's using more cpu. Try to run it on real device to save some RAM too. And if you are running for Android install `cmdline-tools` from Android Studio.

Comment: @fsbelinda yes I am running the app project on a real device, I am not using the emulator, but it's doesn't work, and without cmdline-tools it works for first time

Comment: Okay. You can also try to create a new project with same name as this one and copy `lib` folder, `pubspec.yaml` and other non-default folders & files from the old project to the new one and run.

Comment: @fsbelinda from previous weeks I did this for the run of my project, but I am very frustrated with this, so I need to fix this.